# Order by field mysql command doesn't work, gives wrong order

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a strange problem. I tried this command in mysql:

```
  SELECT `type`, 
         `bought` 
    FROM cars 
   WHERE owner = 'test' 
ORDER BY type
```

And it prints out this in phpmyadmin:

```
type    bought
--------------------
17      1281025497
22      1287708417
22      1287347244
24      1287708324
24      1287876461
6       1287896659
9       1287847238
```

This doesn't make any sense. 17 is bigger than 22 and 9 less than 6?!

Comment: You don't need to put all your columns in backticks. "bought" is most likely not a reserved keyword and you didn't put "cars" and "owner" in backticks so better don't use any backticks at all unless you actually have to use a reserved word as a column name ("type" might be reserved; check the MySQL docs for that)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It definitely looks like type column's type is varchar or text (or any string type, really). You **have** to use an integer type. It is entirely normal that the *string* "10" is lesser than the *string* "6" (1 comes before 6).

If you really don't want to change your column's type, you can cast it to an integer.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT `type`, `bought` FROM cars WHERE owner='test' ORDER BY CAST(`type` AS SIGNED)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's correct if `type` is a `char` field.

If they're chars, you're not comparing the *numbers* six and twenty-four, you're comparing the *strings* "6" and "24".

"6" is greater than "2", so it comes after.